# Angular 6/7 redirecting my web api to default routing

Tags: angular6, angular-routing

My website is hosted on the same domain as my web API.

I'm having a problem that, whenever I try to access my api URL: mywebsite.com/api, i get redirected to the NotFound page.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Bellow are routes on my application:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home',               component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**',                 component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```